# Why doesn't my stored procedure work for given parameters?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a stored procedure which requires 3 parameters. `CaseNo, DateFrom, DateTo`. I have wrote it the way that it should return records in these scenarios.

1. Passing only CaseNo
2. Passing only Dates range
3. Passing both 1 & 2

It works for dates range but not for CaseNo i.e. it returns every caseNo's record not only passed CaseNo e.g. if I pass Case-02 then it returns records for Case-01, Case-03, Case-04 etc. **WHY** ?

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Reportcaseandhearingsbycasenoanddates] 
    @CaseNo VARCHAR(20), 
    @DateFrom DATE, 
    @DateTo DATE 
AS 
BEGIN 
    SELECT 
        cases.pk_cases_caseid, 
        cases.casetitle, 
        cases.casepetitioner, 
        cases.caseno, 
        cases.caseletterby, 
        cases.caseentrydatetime, 
        casehearings.pk_casehearings_id, 
        casehearings.responder, 
        casehearings.supervisor, 
        casehearings.judge, 
        casehearings.isopeningdate, 
        casehearings.isopeningclosingdate, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, casehearings.closingdate, 106) AS ClosingDate, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, casehearings.reopeningdate, 106) AS ReOpeningDate, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, casehearings.openingdate, 106) AS OpeningDate, 
        casehearings.isconveyed, 
        casehearings.isclosingdate, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, casehearings.hearingdate, 106) AS HearingDate, 
        casehearings.fk_concernedoffices_casehearings_concernedofficeid, 
        casehearings.courtorder, 
        casehearings.caseremarks, 
        concernedoffices.concernedofficename, 
        courts.courtname, 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, casehearings.generaldate, 106) AS GeneralDate, 
        casehearings.ishearingdate 
    FROM   
        cases 
    LEFT JOIN 
        casehearings ON cases.pk_cases_caseid = casehearings.fk_cases_casehearings_caseid 
    LEFT JOIN 
        concernedoffices ON concernedoffices.pk_concernedoffices_id = casehearings.fk_concernedoffices_casehearings_concernedofficeid 
    LEFT JOIN 
        courts ON courts.pk_courts_courtid = casehearings.fk_courts_casehearings_courtid 
    INNER JOIN 
        web_users ON web_users.userid = cases.fk_webusers_cases_userid 
    WHERE  
        cases.caseno LIKE '%' + @CaseNo + '%' 
        OR (casehearings.generaldate >= @DateFrom 
            AND casehearings.generaldate <= @DateTo) 
END
```

I have left joined because sometimes tables can contain values that might not exist.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server 2008 or 2012?  Please don't tag both.

Comment: Your filter includes `OR`, so if CaseNo doesn't match but the Dates do, you'll still get a match.  I think if you just change to `AND` based logic it will work.

Comment: In Scenario 1 what you will pass for dates

Comment: @SlimsGhost I checked on AND but that doesn't work and when I removed dates then it work

Comment: @VR46 just empty strings

Comment: @Siyual testing on both, 2008 and 2012

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
...
(cases.caseno LIKE '%' + @CaseNo + '%' or @CaseNo is NULL) and
(casehearings.generaldate >= @DateFrom or @DateFrom is NULL) AND 
(casehearings.generaldate <= @DateTo or @DateTo is NULL)
```

The problem with this kind of SQL is that it will never use any indexes. If you have a lot of data, you should either have 2 different cases (maybe separate procedure) or use dynamic SQL and execute it with sp_executesql

Comment: not working it just return each caseno only once not multiple times i.e. i have different casehearing entries for each case in casehearings table

Comment: Then the problem is not at all your search criteria but rest of the SQL. I can't help with that since I don't know your tables & data

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is what you are looking for

```
  .....
       LEFT JOIN casehearings 
              ON cases.pk_cases_caseid = 
                 casehearings.fk_cases_casehearings_caseid 
                 AND (( casehearings.generaldate >= @DateFrom 
                       AND casehearings.generaldate <= @DateTo 
                       AND @DateFrom <> '' 
                       AND @DateTo <> '' ) or (@DateFrom = '' and @DateTo = '' ))
 .....
WHERE  ( cases.caseno LIKE '%' + @CaseNo + '%' 
         AND @CaseNo <> '' ) 
   OR  ( userID = @userID
         AND @CaseNo <> '' )
```

There are two mistakes in your query

**Empty string** will be converted to `1900-01-01` so you will get all the records since the dates is present in `OR` condition.

If you keep the right table `filter` in `Where` clause the `Left Outer Join` will be implicitly converted to `INNER JOIN` so move the `filter's` to `ON` clause

Comment: Oh wow. thanks, it worked but still i don't get that how did it work ? especially this <>

Comment: @StackyFlowy - I have explained the problem

Comment: @StackyFlowy - Check now

Comment: yes sir I checked but It doesn't work when I add more conditions i.e. not much flexible. I have added UserID i.e. it should look for the userid of user who has inserted the date

Comment: @StackyFlowy - Where did you add `UserID` and how

Comment: @StackyFlowy - check is that how you added

Comment: @StackyFlowy - My final try check now else am deleting my answer. It is difficult to write query without looking at the data

Comment: thanks a lot for helping me out, I did bit of editing to your code and it worked like a charm. Please look at my answer I have posted now and put it in your code so I CAN ACCEPT YOUR ANSWER

Answer (score 0):

Maybe This?

```
Where Cases.CaseNo like '%'+ @CaseNo +'%' OR
         ( CaseHearings.GeneralDate >= @DateFrom
         AND CaseHearings.GeneralDate <= @DateTo)
```

Its the OR condition..  As long as the date range is correct.. you will get all cases back that fit..

UPDATED Answer

```
WHERE 

 CASE WHEN  @CaseNo <> '' AND @DateFrom <> '' AND @DateTo <> '' AND 
          CaseHearings.GeneralDate >= @DateFrom
          AND CaseHearings.GeneralDate <= @DateTo 
          AND cases.caseno LIKE '%' + @CaseNo + '%' 
         THEN 1
      WHEN @CaseNO = '' AND  @DateFrom <> '' AND @DateTo <> '' AND
           CaseHearings.GeneralDate >= @DateFrom
           AND CaseHearings.GeneralDate <= @DateTo 
         THEN 1
      WHEN @CaseNO <> '' AND  @DateFrom = '' AND @DateTo = '' AND
          AND cases.caseno LIKE '%' + @CaseNo + '%' 
         THEN 1
      ELSE 0 END = 1
```

Comment: Check your parms.. are they emtpy strings, are they null?  what are you passing in your three cases.. can you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is because you are filtering the dates in the `WHERE` clause, but that table is the right-hand side of a `LEFT JOIN`.  This is causing the `LEFT JOIN` to behave as an `INNER JOIN`, and since you aren't passing in the dates, it is failing the condition.

You should move that to the `ON` clause for the `LEFT JOIN`.  Additionally, you should add a condition for when the dates or caseno are `NULL`:

```
Select      Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID, Cases.CaseTitle, Cases.CasePetitioner, Cases.CaseNo, Cases.CaseLetterBy, Cases.CaseEntryDateTime,
            CaseHearings.pk_CaseHearings_ID, CaseHearings.Responder, CaseHearings.Supervisor, CaseHearings.Judge, CaseHearings.IsOpeningDate,
            CaseHearings.IsOpeningClosingDate, Convert(varchar, CaseHearings.ClosingDate, 106) as ClosingDate, Convert(varchar, CaseHearings.ReOpeningDate, 106) as ReOpeningDate , 
            Convert(varchar, CaseHearings.OpeningDate, 106) as OpeningDate , CaseHearings.IsConveyed, 
            CaseHearings.IsClosingDate, Convert(varchar, CaseHearings.HearingDate, 106) as HearingDate, CaseHearings.fk_ConcernedOffices_CaseHearings_ConcernedOfficeID, CaseHearings.CourtOrder, 
            CaseHearings.CaseRemarks, ConcernedOffices.ConcernedOfficeName, Courts.CourtName, Convert(varchar,CaseHearings.GeneralDate, 106) as GeneralDate, CaseHearings.IsHearingDate 
From        Cases
left Join   CaseHearings        ON  Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID= CaseHearings.fk_Cases_CaseHearings_CaseID
                                AND ((@DateFrom Is Null And @DateTo Is Null)
                                    OR (CaseHearings.GeneralDate >= @DateFrom
                                        AND CaseHearings.GeneralDate <= @DateTo
                                        )
                                    )
left Join   ConcernedOffices    ON  ConcernedOffices.pk_ConcernedOffices_ID= CaseHearings.fk_ConcernedOffices_CaseHearings_ConcernedOfficeID
left Join   Courts              ON  Courts.pk_Courts_CourtID= CaseHearings.fk_Courts_CaseHearings_CourtID
Inner Join  Web_Users           ON  Web_Users.UserID= Cases.fk_WebUsers_Cases_UserID
Where (@CaseNo Is Null Or (@CaseNo Is Not Null And Cases.CaseNo like '%'+ @CaseNo +'%')
```

Comment: not working sir, It just shows each caseNO once rather it should show all records i.e. each caseno has many casehearings in CaseHearings table

Comment: any help ? please help

Comment: @StackyFlowy What are the values of the parameters when you aren't supplying them?  Are they something other than `NULL`?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks community for helping me out. I tried what @VR46 suggested and did bit editing and it worked

```
Select      Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID, Cases.CaseTitle, Cases.CasePetitioner, Cases.CaseNo, Cases.CaseLetterBy, Cases.CaseEntryDateTime,
            CaseHearings.pk_CaseHearings_ID, CaseHearings.Responder, CaseHearings.Supervisor, CaseHearings.Judge, CaseHearings.IsOpeningDate,
            CaseHearings.IsOpeningClosingDate, Convert(varchar, CaseHearings.ClosingDate, 106) as ClosingDate, Convert(varchar, CaseHearings.ReOpeningDate, 106) as ReOpeningDate , 
            Convert(varchar, CaseHearings.OpeningDate, 106) as OpeningDate , CaseHearings.IsConveyed, 
            CaseHearings.IsClosingDate, Convert(varchar, CaseHearings.HearingDate, 106) as HearingDate, CaseHearings.fk_ConcernedOffices_CaseHearings_ConcernedOfficeID, CaseHearings.CourtOrder, 
            CaseHearings.CaseRemarks, ConcernedOffices.ConcernedOfficeName, Courts.CourtName, Convert(varchar,CaseHearings.GeneralDate, 106) as GeneralDate, CaseHearings.IsHearingDate 
From        Cases
left Join   CaseHearings        ON  Cases.pk_Cases_CaseID= CaseHearings.fk_Cases_CaseHearings_CaseID
                                AND ((@DateFrom ='' And @DateTo ='')
                                    OR (CaseHearings.GeneralDate >= @DateFrom
                                        AND CaseHearings.GeneralDate <= @DateTo
                                        )
                                    )
left Join   ConcernedOffices    ON  ConcernedOffices.pk_ConcernedOffices_ID= CaseHearings.fk_ConcernedOffices_CaseHearings_ConcernedOfficeID
left Join   Courts              ON  Courts.pk_Courts_CourtID= CaseHearings.fk_Courts_CaseHearings_CourtID
Inner Join  Web_Users           ON  Web_Users.UserID= Cases.fk_WebUsers_Cases_UserID
Where (@CaseNo ='' Or (@CaseNo!='' And Cases.CaseNo like '%'+ @CaseNo +'%')) AND Web_Users.UserID=@UserID
```